# How to use user session in yii1.x console command

Tags: php, yii

I am using `Yii1.x` framework console command. On this command I am using trying to use user session like

```
Yii::app()->user->user_id;
```

its showing error in command.
But same thing is working with application.

Comment: Please check on this [link](http://pasteboard.co/MHWtT7B.png)

Comment: Please edit your *question* with all relevant information posting error messages as plain text where possible - which it is here. Images do not help future users - what if the link changes?

Comment: If you want to access information between a web application and the cli application then you need the web-application to store the information in a place the cli-application can access it. So, one way, have a database table linked to the user called something like `web_cli_shared_data`?

Comment: @RyanVincent its worked for me thanks, I communicate to application using database table so that we can access user related information using this table, As of now I can not get any stuff to work directly yii::app()->user-> in my yii console command.

Comment: You know the user id as you passed it to the cli - it should be simple to load that user model in yii? Not sure about using `app()` as that will be for the `web` stuff. Use the models directly to do what you want.

Comment: Yes as of now I did same thing, not used app(), just passed user id and then get its details by loading model.

Comment: glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii 1.x Console App, cannot access class CWebUser, because in order for CWebUser to be set, it is dependent on Web Technologies such as Cookies etc and console apps dont have access to that tech.